# Variables in .properties file?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to use variables in Kafka config files like server.properties? I tried `${MY_VAR}`, but that didn't work. Getting kind of annoying to update all the paths every time the version changes. I updated some of my batch files to use `%~dp0`, etc. but that doesn't solve the .properties file issue.

Comment: Could you give us an example of a path and your server.properties file?

Comment: @Ismail Right now for example, my log.dirs=/progra~1/kafka_2.13-2.6.0/logs and other stuff like certs is based on the bath. Yeah, I know I can get rid of the version # in the path or move that stuff to a static path, just trying to keep it organized.

Comment: Why do you bother putting versions in the filepaths anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Kafka is using this class for reading reading server configuration (and other configuration files): [`org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.java`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java)

In the code Kafka is using [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class for reading properties.
As you can see from documentation it does not support variables in properties.

Answer (score 0):

a little tricky

a sample server.properties

```
...
    zookeeper.connect=$ZOOKEEPER_HOST:$ZOOKEEPER_PORT
...
```

then crate your own bash start with:

```
export ZOOKEEPER_HOST=192.168.1.100
export ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181
### reemplacing with .env values
envsubst "`printf '${%s} ' $(sh -c "env|cut -d'=' -f1")`" < ../config/server.properties > srv.properties 
./kafka-server-start.sh srv.properties
```